# Remove repetition of javascript html tag creation

Tags: javascript, html

If you go through the process of creating html elements in JavaScript, you can see that this process is repeated a lot. For example I made a function to create, edit and delete comments in real time, please see the following code.

```js
function addComment(comment, score) {
  // Create a list for comments
  const newComment = document.createElement('li');
  newComment.setAttribute('data-commentid', comment._id);
  newComment.classList.add('detail__comment');

  // Creating a Comments Information
  const commentInfo = document.createElement('div');
  commentInfo.classList.add('detail__comment__info');

  const scoreConfigWrap = document.createElement('div');
  scoreConfigWrap.classList.add('detail__comment__score');
  for (let i = 0; i < score; i++) {
    const filledScore = document.createElement('i');
    const filledScoreClass = ['fa-solid', 'fa-star', 'filled'];
    filledScore.classList.add(...filledScoreClass);
    scoreConfigWrap.appendChild(filledScore);
  }
  for (let j = score; j < 5; j++) {
    const score = document.createElement('i');
    const scoreClass = ['fa-solid', 'fa-star'];
    score.classList.add(...scoreClass);
    scoreConfigWrap.appendChild(score);
  }

  // Create a comment edit button and include it in its parent
  const commentBtns = document.createElement('div');
  commentBtns.classList.add('detail__comment__btns');
  const modifyBtn = document.createElement('button');
  modifyBtn.innerText = 'Update';
  modifyBtn.classList.add('detail__comment__modify-btn');
  const cancelModifyBtn = document.createElement('button');
  cancelModifyBtn.innerText = 'Cancel';
  cancelModifyBtn.classList.add('detail__comment__modify-cancel');
  cancelModifyBtn.classList.add('hidden');
  commentBtns.appendChild(modifyBtn);
  commentBtns.appendChild(cancelModifyBtn);
  commentInfo.appendChild(scoreConfigWrap);
  commentInfo.appendChild(commentBtns);

  // Create space for comment text, author
  const commentText = document.createElement('div');
  commentText.classList.add('detail__comment__text');
  const span = document.createElement('span');
  span.innerText = comment.text;
  const commentOwner = document.createElement('a');
  commentOwner.setAttribute('href', `users/${comment.owner._id}`);
  commentOwner.innerText = comment.owner.uid;
  commentText.appendChild(span);
  commentText.appendChild(commentOwner);

  // Create a delete comment button
  const deleteBtn = document.createElement('button');
  deleteBtn.innerText = 'X';
  deleteBtn.classList.add('detail__comment__delete');

  // Saving information to be used for comment editing and deletion functions
  comment = {
    text: comment.text,
    _id: comment._id,
  };
  commentObj = {
    comment,
    commentBtns,
    commentElement: commentText,
  };

  // Link all elements related to comments with their parent
  newComment.appendChild(commentInfo);
  newComment.appendChild(commentText);
  newComment.appendChild(modifyForm);
  newComment.appendChild(deleteBtn);
  detailComments.prepend(newComment);
}
```

Doesn't it make you annoyed just by looking at it? The problem is I don't know how to refactor this iteration. I thought about making the process of creating html elements into a separate function.

```js
export default function createHtmlTag(
  element,
  text,
  attrObj,
  className,
  parentNode
) {
  const newElement = document.createElement(element);
  if (attrObj) {
    newElement.setAttribute(attrObj.key, attrObj.value);
  }
  if (text) {
    newElement.innerText = text;
  }
  if (className) {
    newElement.classList.add(className);
  }
  parentNode.appendChild(newElement);
}
```

But even then, the code looked like it was less readable. So I'd like to get a little hint about the refactoring process.

Comment: I don't know if it's a personal project or a assignment to do for your studies, but you should definitely look into VueJS, otherwise you'll struggle with thousands of lines of repetitive code.

Comment: @djcaesar9114 This is a personal project. In fact, before learning the JS library, I was making a project with pure JavaScript. I think I will have to recreate it with React or Vue next time. Thank you for answer.

Comment: Use jquery as it simplifies DOM traversal and manipulation.